# Asp.net MVC Loading Parent View from the actionlink of PartialView using Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I need to call ParentView from its partial view. Like I have list of ToDos in Partial view where Ajax actionlink is used to edit the data in parent by passing its id. The same is working without using Ajax as it is manipulating url by putting querystring. But we would like to have internal call with Ajax which is not firing.

**The code we are using is like that:**

```
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink(@item.ToDoTitle, "Index", new { tdid = @item.ToDoId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "saved", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod="POST" })</li>
```

**and controller is like that:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int tdid =0)
    {
        if (tdid !=0)
        {
            ToDo t = new ToDo();
            t.ToDoTitle = "Ramlal";
            t.ToDoDesc = "Shyamlal";
            t.ToDoId = tdid;
            return Json(t);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

We have tried the same with returning a view but nothing have happened, so we have tried to use Json as it returning model.

Correct me if I am wrong?

FYI, this is the parent view:

```
@model myTask.Models.ToDo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Task";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "MyTaskList" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="MyTask">
        @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.ToDoId)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(t => t.ToDoTitle)<br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.ToDoTitle)
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(t => t.ToDoDesc)<br />
                @Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.ToDoDesc)
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $( "#ToDoTitle" ).blur( function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Save",
                    type: "POST",
                data: $("#form0").serialize(),
                dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (model) {
                $("#ToDoId").val(model.ToDoId);
                $("#ToDoTitle").val(model.ToDoTitle);
                $("#ToDoDesc").val(model.ToDoDesc);
            });
            });

            $("#ToDoDesc").blur(function () {
                if ($("#ToDoId").val() > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Save",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $("#form0").serialize(),
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).done(function (model) {
                        $("#ToDoId").val(model.ToDoId);
                        $("#ToDoTitle").val(model.ToDoTitle);
                        $("#ToDoDesc").val(model.ToDoDesc);
                    });
                }});
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="ObjectList" id="MyTaskList">
        @Html.Action("TodoList")
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
}
```

This is partial view which is being called using @Html.Action("TodoList")

```
@using System.Linq
@model myTask.Models.ToDoList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    @if (Model.ToDos.Count > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ToDos)
            {
                @*<li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.ToDoTitle, "Index", new { tdid = @item.ToDoId })</li>*@
                <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(@item.ToDoTitle, "/Index", new { tdid = @item.ToDoId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "MyTask", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST" })</li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
using myTask.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace myTask.Controllers
{
    public class TasktdController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Tasktd
        public ActionResult Index(int tdid =0)
        {
            if (tdid !=0)
            {
                ToDo t = new ToDo();
                t.ToDoTitle = "Ramlal";
                t.ToDoDesc = "Shyamlal";
                t.ToDoId = tdid;
                return PartialView(t);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Save(ToDo td)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            ModelState.Remove("ToDoId");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var t = await td.Save(td);
                return Json(td);
            }
            return Json("Oops! Error Occured");
        }
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult TodoList()
        {
            ToDoList tdl = new ToDoList();
            List <ToDo> tds= new List<ToDo>();
            ToDo t = new ToDo();
            t.ToDoId = 1;
            t.ToDoTitle = "XXX";
            tds.Add(t);
            tdl.ToDos = tds;
            return PartialView(tdl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning json?

Comment: Edit your question (not in comments!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke We have edited the question as you have suggested.

Comment: Still not clear what your trying to do. Your `@Ajax.ActionLink()` method calls the `Index()` method which returns json, not a partial view

Comment: @StephenMuecke We are beginner in MVC, so don;t know much about it, we simply like to load single object in parent from list of objects in partial. Appreciate if you could suggest a demo.

Comment: Not sure exactly what your mean. Firstly your `$( "#ToDoTitle" ).blur()` and `$("#ToDoDesc").blur()` functions make no sense at all  - you need to delete them!. Are you wanting to click on a link and update the form controls with the `ToDoTitle` and `ToDoDesc` of the selected item so that you can edit them?

Comment: @StephenMuecke both the functions are saving the data in database on lostfocus. Also, we are not having trouble with this view. The problem is with TodoList, I am editing the form again. to have you are clear view.

Comment: Sorry, but _"saving the data in database on lostfocus"_ is nonsense (and you are having trouble since neither of those scripts work). But you need to explain clearly what is that your trying to do (since the code you have shown has no relationship to your question). What do you expect to happen when you click on the link?

Comment: @StephenMuecke When the linked in clicked, a relevant model should open in the parent view and show its data in the form as mentioned above. Editing and providing entire controller.

Comment: It is working fine if we don't use Ajax.ActionLink and use Html.ActionLink, but that post the form to get it done by putting the id in querystring but we just dont like to refresh the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a number of problems with your code. First your submitting the form using `.ajax()` - and the form does not even have a submit button anyway! Replace

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", new AjaxOptions() { ... })
{
  ....
}
```

with

```
<form id="form">
  .... // add controls for properties
  <button id="save" type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

and remove the scripts for `$( "#ToDoTitle" ).blur()` and `$("#ToDoDesc").blur()` and replace with

```
<script>
  var form = $('#form');
  var saveUrl = '@Url.Action("Save")';
  $.post(saveUrl, form.serialize(), function(data) {
    if(data) {
      // save successful - give the user some feedback
    }
  }).fail(function (result) {
    // Oops and error occurred - give the user some feedback
  });
  .... // add script for editing here (see below0
</script>
```

Your current scripts result in poor performance and are the result of a bad UI design. The user should decide when to save (i.e by clicking a button), not you. Consider what happens if the user edits the title and tabs to the description then realizes that all was correct and nothing needed to be changed afterall (you code has already altered the data in the database and the user would not even know it)

Note the script should be immediately before the closing `</body>` tag (not inline). And the `Save()` method should return `Json(true)` if the objects was successfully saved.

To handle clicking the 'links', change the partial to (note the `@if` block it not required)

```
<ul>
  @foreach (var item in Model.ToDos)
  {
    <li>
      <span>@item.ToDoTitle</span>
      <button class="edit" type="button" data-id="@item.@item.ToDoId">Edit</button>
    </li>
  }
</ul>
```

And if you want the button to look like a link, then use css to style it

Then add another script in the main view

```
var editUrl = '@Url.Action("Get")';
$('.edit').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var title = $(this).prev('span').text();
  $.getJSON(editUrl, { id: id, function(data) {
    // Populate form fields
    $('#ToDoId').val(id);
    $('#ToDoTitle').val(title);
    $('#ToDoDesc').val(data);
  });
});
```

And the controller method would be

```
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
  // Look up the Description based on the id, for example
  string description = db.ToDo.Where(x => x.ToDoId == id).Select(x => x.ToDoDesc);
  return Json(description, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note, you already have the ID and Title properties in the view so its only necessary to return the Description (and I suggest you change your property names as suggested here - i.e. `ID`, `Title` and `Description`)

Comment: You are correct, we had completely wrong approach to have partial view loaded with Javascript and other stuff, so we have combined both the view and have provided another Viewmodel. We also feel Blur event has drawbacks and each time we leave input box, it will communicate with server.